# Overheating While Screen Locked

Tags: applications, lock-screens, nexus-5, overheating

I have a Nexus 5 running stock Lollipop and lately I have noticed that when I lock the screen, but leave an app (or multiple apps) open (e.g. Chrome, Facebook, Youtube) the phone gets very hot and the battery drains like crazy. It's like the phone is acting as if the screen is still on.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Next time the phone gets hot, like how you were describing. When you turn it on. Go to Settings > Battery > And see what is at the top of the list. It sounds like an app is keeping the device awake, even with the screen off. This should at least tell you what app it is then we can do from there.

Comment: I have done that, and nothing is jumping out - Android OS and Google Services top the list but are only like 3-5% each.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar kind of issue with initial Lollipop version 5.0. I had clean master installed in my phone which showed that nearly 60-70% of RAM and CPU usage even though no apps were running, which end up heating my phone.

When checked in Settings-->Apps-->Running application mostly were services from android os. But they have now improved it in newer version of lollipop...currently my phone has version 5.1.1. In this it drop from 60-70% to 40% RAM and CPU usage.

Also lollipop has lot of bugs you can find a consolidated list here - https://www.androidpit.com/android-5-0-lollipop-problems-and-solutions